# Why sometimes cin.ignore request input?

Tags: c++, buffer, cin, getline

Usually,cin.ignore(N,M) will ignore N characters in istream before encountered character 'M'.
But,in the below program,it will wait for input after cin.clear().So,why is it?What's the usage of cin.ignore().

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char* alg = new char[40];
    clog << "getline" << endl;
    cin.getline(alg, 40, '\n');
    clog << "clear" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    clog << "ignore" << endl;
    cin.ignore(65536, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the result in MSVC Terminal:

```
test
clear
ignore
test
```

Comment: If there's no current input, then it must wait for input that matches the conditions in the arguments (either `65536` characters read and discarded, or a newline `'\n'`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Though the previous input before cin.ignore is "test"then I press the Enter key，it should be a newline '\n',it requests another input.

Comment: You read the first input with `getline`, including the newline. Then you clear the stream status, and ask to read more input with the `ignore` call.